# c# CATIA: ошибка System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, com

При работе с CATIA с помощью c# возникает ошибка:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'
```

Момент возникновения:
Попытка сохранить файлы в каталог, в который сохранял прошлый раз. При создании нового через `folderBrowserDialog` - ошибка не возникает, но при следующей записи в этот же каталог - возникает вновь.

Код:

```
 string pathQ = tb_path.Text;  // var pathQ = tb_path.Text;
            
 for (int iDoc = 1; iDoc < CATIA.Documents.Count; iDoc++)
                {
                    Document active = null;
                    active = CATIA.ActiveDocument;
                    // CATIA.Documents.Item(iDoc).Activate();
                    Document docc = null;
                    docc = CATIA.Documents.Item(iDoc);
    
                   
                    string nn = CATIA.Documents.Item(iDoc).get_Name();
                    
                   
                  
                    docc.SaveAs(pathQ + "\\" + nn);  //<----ОШИБКА ТУТ
                    
            }
```

Много информации прочел и на данном форуме, и на сторонних, но с ошибкой так и не разобрался.
Усложняет вопрос ещё то,что мало информации по самой CATIA в c#.
Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой либо знает решение.
Спасибо!

Comment: Бросилось в глаза вот это: int iDoc = 1; Там точно счет с единицы начинается?

Comment: @gbg Да, не с 0 и не с 2. Вот пример, который который написан на CATScript:
For v = 1 To oDocs.Count

If TypeName(oDocs.Item(v)) = "PartDocument" Then
Set oDoc2 = oDocs.Item(v)
Set oPart1 = oDoc2.Product
oDoc2.SaveAs docPath & "\" & oPart1.PartNumber & ".CATPart"
End If
Next 

Msgbox "Save Finished!",,"SAVE FINISH!"

Comment: Тогда непонятно, почему условие продолжения цикла  <, а не <=

Comment: @gbg Спасибо за подсказку, ушла проблема пропуска некоторых элементов дерева. Но прошлая осталась: создал НоваяПапка1. Сохранил туда.Всё хорошо. Новая структура дерева появилась. На форме есть textbox с путем к этой папке. Нажимаю снова сохранить - ошибка та же: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'

Comment: А если перед повторным сохранением удалить результаты прошлого сохранения? Может, он не хочет переписывать файлы поверх

Comment: @gbg подскажите, что Вы имеете ввиду под удалить прошлые? физически с диска? либо в самой программе "мусор"?